# Why does pretty much every attempt to merge changes from remote with Git turn into SCS hell?

Tags: git, merge

I have a clean local repository.

I perform a fetch and see several new changesets.

I perform a merge to master. This errors saying some files cannot be written, so I abort the merge.

At this point my local repository is a complete mess, because even though I've aborted the merge Git hasn't bothered to return it to the clean state it was in before and has instead decided to just leave it looking like a trashed wasteland of a half performed merge that has failed. Does Git not have any notion of an atomic operation that either succeeds or fails?

So now if I reattempt the merge it will complain that the merge will try to overwrite untracked files (the mess it left behind from the first merge). To fix this I have to trawl through the log and locate every single file that Git added in its screwed up attempt to perform the orginal merge and manually delete them, before I can even start trying to work out what caused the original merge to fail in the first place.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this kind of manual intervention to remedy the simplest issue just par for the course when working with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the "trashed wasteland of a half performed merge", just

```
git reset --hard branchname
```

Also, by "merge to master" you probably mean merge *from* master, right? Another option is to rebase your branch on the fetched remote one, but you still need to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: I mean merging from the newly fetched origin/master to master. 'git reset --hard branchname' looks very useful. Thanks.